# How to center content and keep the indicated size in CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I would like to create a grid of squares with their content centered:

```css
#all {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 20px 200px;
}

.disp {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: gray;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800');
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div id="all">
  <span class="disp hour">9</span><span class="sep"> </span><span class="disp min">27</span>
</div>
```

I cannot make the `9` centered and preserve the `200px` width at the same time. Replacing the last CSS line with `justify-self: center;` does center the `9`, but also reduces the width of the cell to make it fit. The width of the grid is preserved.

**How to say "center and expand to the width of the cell" in CSS Grid?**

Comment: `text-align: center;` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: that was it, thanks. I believe that I also understood that `justify-self` is just about how the container of the cell will behave (fit and left, fit and right, stretched), independently of the positioning of the content.Would you mind turning this into an answer?

Comment: yes exactly, justify-self is to center the whole element and what you need is to cented what is inside the element

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `text-align:center`

Add this in your CSS code:

If you want only 9 centered:

```
.hour {
   text-align:center;
}
```

If you want both centered:

```
.disp {
   text-align:center;
}
```

Tested in Chrome `Inspect Element`.

Same trick works with the `.min` class too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
  .hour {
      text-align:center;
    }
```